# アクションフォームからJSPへデータ受け渡し

Tags: java, struts

Struts 1.3 を用いて開発しています。
アクションフォームからJSPにデータを渡したいと考えています。
流れとしては以下の通りです。

・XxxAction.javaでDBから値を取得
　　　　↓
・yyy.jspのhtml:hiddenに値を渡す
　　　　↓
・Zzz.Action.javaでyyy.jspのhidden項目の値取得

ソースは以下のものを考えました。

`XxxAction.java`

```java
public final class XxxAction extends Action {
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping,
        ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest req,
        HttpServletResponse res){

        //DBから値取得
        //省略

        session.setAttribute("Aaa", aaa);
                return (mapping.findForward("success"));
    }
}
```

`yyy.jsp`

```html
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>

<!-- 省略 -->

<html:hidden property="Aaa" value="<bean:write name="Aaa"scope="session"/>"/>
<!-- 文法的に間違っていたり、値が間違っていたりしますが、
上記のようなことをやりたいです-->

<html:link action="/action">リンク</html:link>
<!-- linkの/actionでhiddenの値を送信　zzz.jspへ -->

<!-- 省略 -->
```

`ZzzAction.java`

```java
public final class ZzzAction extends Action{
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {

        YyyForm yyyForm = (YyyForm)form;

        String str = yyyForm.getAaa();

        //省略

    }
}
```

疑問点としては

1． どのようにJSPファイルのhtml:hiddenに値を渡すか (html:hiddenの記述の仕方)
2． html:linkのactionで値をどのように渡すか

です。

Struts初心者のため、初歩的な部分も理解しきれていません。
また、質問が非常に分かりずらく、申し訳ないですが、
是非、回答よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> session.setAttribute("Aaa", aaa);

セッションに属性をセットしたので、`ZzzAction`の中で`session.getAttribute("Aaa");`すれば値を取得できます。

hidden項目にセットして、再度リクエストパラメータとして渡す必要はありません。そうしなければならない理由があるようでしたら、その理由を追記して下さい。

Comment: Kohei TAMURA さん　回答ありがとうございます。　>セッションに属性をセットしたので、ZzzActionの中でsession.getAttribute("Aaa");すれば値を取得できます。　　確かに今回のケースではhiddenに渡してから取得する必要はありませんでした。ですが、別のケースでhtml:textに表示させる必要があるのですが、その場合どうするべきなのでしょう？今のところ `<input type="text" name="Aaa" value="<bean:write name="Aaa"/>">` と記述していますが、これは正しいのでしょうか？

Comment: Strutsは大昔に開発で使っていたので、あまり覚えていませんが...`bean:write`ではなく、`property`でActionFormから取得するのがベタな方法だったような気がします。おそらく[このページ](https://ameblo.jp/arahism123/entry-10359213262.html)が参考になると思います。